# GLMMadaptive - Warning message: In sqrt(diag(var_betas)) : NaNs produced

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, fitting

I ran the following model and this warning came out, what does this mean?

model:

```
 mixed_model(fixed = logRT ~ B * P * S * t, 
random = ~1 | Participant, data = Data, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

output:

```
 Fixed effects:
                                    Estimate Std.Err  z-value   p-value
 (Intercept)                               2.0106     NaN      NaN        NA
 ....

 Optimization:
 method: hybrid EM and quasi-Newton
 converged: TRUE 
 Warning message:
 In sqrt(diag(var_betas)) : NaNs produced
```

Answer (score 1):

This warning message and the corresponding output indicate that the optimization algorithm was not successful. In particular, for a Gamma mixed it would be better to use the `Gamma.fam()` implemented in the package. Also, you can have a look in the advice on how to alter the optimization defaults [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Optimization.html#advice-on-optimization-and-numerical-integration-control-1).

Comment: Thank you, I will check the resources. Will the resids_plot function be available for gamma distributions?

Comment: @CatM yes it should work but you need to install the most recent version from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that I should put family = Gamma.fam()?

Comment: Error in Gamma.fam() : could not find function "Gamma.fam"

Comment: @CatM install the most recent version from GitHub.

Comment: Just did, now says: Error: 'family' argument seems not to be a valid family object

Comment: @CatM sorry for the late response, it should work now...

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Though it does not produce any outcome and spits out this message: "Error in mixed_fit(y, X, Z, X_zi, Z_zi, id, offset, offset_zi, family, : A large coefficient value has been detected during the optimization. Please re-scale you covariates and/or try setting the control argument 'iter_EM = 0'. Alternatively, this may due to a divergence of the optimization algorithm, indicating that an overly complex model is fitted to the data....

Comment: For example, this could be caused when including random-effects terms (e.g., in the zero-inflated part) that you do not need. Otherwise, adjust the 'max_coef_value' control argument." Could you explain? I am using a somewhat simple model given that I have a dataset with more than 83000 rows.

Comment: @CatM as suggested in the message try `mixed_model(..., iter_EM = 0, max_coef_value = 50)`.

Comment: Still spits out the same message even though I increases the max_coef_value to 1000 :) Not sure why this is happening since it works with glmer.